# My CSS code is not working in the Chrome, neither inline CSS, internal CSS or external

Tags: html, css

My CSS code is not working in the Chrome. Either it is inline CSS, internal CSS or external CSS - none of them is working in my HTML file.
I have already tried clearing cache of both Chrome and Microsoft Edge and I am using VS Code. When I open the HTML file from my computer or either from Live server it does not update. I have tried to hard reset, cleared the cache, restarted my computer but it doesn't update. The HTML works fine but the CSS is not working. For example - color is not showing
here is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color: red; background-color: yellowgreen;">This CSS code is not working</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add more information so we can help you,

Comment: Have a look at the styles inspector and find if any other styles are overriding it.

Comment: try this: `<p style="color: red; background-color: #BDF85F;">This CSS code is not working</p>
`

Comment: I've just run the code you provided and it works fine. The only thing I can think of is that some ancestor is setting the colors with a !important set. Could you describe more what you see, and what you mean by 'isn't working'?

Comment: do you have some more code in the file. have a try with new html file(you can generate it with vscode emmet by typing html:5) with a body containing single line of code that you provided.

Comment: Not every *style* comes from a *(Cascaded) Style Sheet*: Please review the terminology and find a better title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file from the folder where it is  and right click on the file and then select open with chrome and your file will work.